# Desktop sharing doesn't work at home

Tags: remote-desktop

I am using Ubuntu 14.04LTS. Recently, I needed to use remote control of my computer in my office. So I set up desktop sharing. I can use my own laptop to control my desktop when I am in the office, however, when I go back home, it doesn't work. I tried to turn off firewall, but it didn't work either.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain how you set up desktop sharing. Are you using an IP or a server name? Are your laptop and desktop connected to the same network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be answering your question as I understand it (not that well):

- you have a PC (PC-1) at work that you enabled desktop sharing
- you used another PC (PC-2) at work (on the same network) to successfully remote into PC-1
- you went went on a home PC (PC-3; different network) & couldn't successfully connect to PC-1 in office

Its because of your router/firewall configuration on your work network-ie SECURITY. Someone will need to port-forward/allow port 5900 (assuming its VNC) on that work router/firewall

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! I'v talked to my network security and they help me solve the problem. It's because port 5900 has already been used. But I can use realVNC to connect with my PC in office.

Comment: No problem. Would you mind marking it as the answer?